# SQL returns no rows via myODB, but in SQL there are rows

Tags: mysql, odbc

I have an SQL table called "tbl_einheit". phpmyadmin shows more than 14.000 rows in the table. When accessing via webpage, the table is empty "eof".

I minimized the SQL Statment, and deleted all WHERE, ORDER BY elements, so that simply

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_einheit
```

is the statement. But it still returns an empty result set. I also tried

```
SELECT E . * FROM tbl_einheit E, ( SELECT @a := NULL ) AS init LIMIT 0,30
```

but also empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the reduced code, which wont work `strConnTT2 = "DSN=conntodb1"

Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")                                                
Conn.Open(strConnTT2)
strSQL = " SELECT * FROM tbl_einheit"

set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)
response.write strSQL & "<br>"
if not rs.eof then
 response.write "not eof"
else
 response.write "eof"
end if`

Comment: Can you access other tables via that same database connection?

Comment: yes, all other tables can be accessed. As posted to the answer, select count(*) returns the correct number of rows, but select * returns an eof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is you have some data type in your mysql dtaabse that ADODB connector in ASSp can't recognize, so asp thinks it is EOF.

use CAST in MySQL to convert data type to something asp can understand, example:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(Entry_Data_1) as UNSIGNED) as score FROM contests_entries
```

Comment: thanks for your input. But it won't work. I migrated the date from MS Access to mySQL. With MS Access the scripts just works fine.

Comment: since count(*) returns a result, but * does not, modify your sql statement to only select 1 column name at a time, and test if result. i.e. select id (returns results), select name (returns nothing). let us know the results, and the data type of the column that is failing to return a result.

Comment: Decimals has to be casted to CHAR. Don't know why, but this solved the problem!

Comment: thanks for the acceptance. it is because the odbc driver for mysql doesn't recognize that data type, and it returns no results. by casting it to another data type in the mysql engine, the odbc recognizes it and passes it to your script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a trace in your code to make sure you are executing the code you think you are.
2. Double-check your connection string.

Comment: did both. renamed the table and the sql trough the web page returned an error, that the table is not found. So I go to the right database, and the right code is executed.

Comment: Try changing your query to `select count(*) from tbl_einheit`

Comment: code is posted above! changed to count(*) returned a result! what the hell am i doing wrong?

Comment: count was the correct number of rows. the same as shown in phpmyadmin

Comment: Try changing `if not rs.eof` to `if not rs.bof and not rs.eof`

Comment: changed like you said but the same result :-( In this project there are a few hundred sql select statements. this is the first time, that i have these troubles. i don't know what to do any more :-(

Comment: problem still exists - any ideas?